# Links in RMarkdown Datatable

Tags: html, r-markdown

I'm trying to create active links in an RMarkdown document. In the code below, the basic kable table is perfect, but the datatable version turns the links into text

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

```
library(knitr)
library(DT)
example.df <- data.frame("link"=c("[Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo)","[Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris)"), "country"=c("Japan","France"))


kable(example.df)
datatable(example.df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, here's the answer: format the links as raw HTML not as RMarkdown syntax http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/cgrb/2019/08/06/r-tips-a-table-makeover-with-dt/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 changes needed to it to work with `datatable`.

1. Format the links as raw HTML, not Markdown
2. Include relevant `escape` arguments as to NOT escape the link column.  For simplicity in this example, we use `escape=FALSE`

Here is a full reprex answer.

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(knitr)
library(DT)
example.df.kable <- data.frame("link"=c("[Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo)","[Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris)"), "country"=c("Japan","France"))

example.df.datatable <- data.frame("link"=c(
'<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo">Tokyo</a>',
'<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris">Paris</a>'),
"country"=c("Japan","France"))

kable(example.df.kable)
datatable(example.df.kable)  # This does NOT show the links
datatable(example.df.datatable)  # This does NOT show the links
datatable(example.df.datatable, escape=FALSE)  # This does show the links
````